# Input fields with char count values (if i use keyup it show exactly but if i use keydow it show incorrect values )

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, keydown, keyup

all input fields with limited chars, am using with jquery function to get proper output
if i use keyup it works fine but not applying to all popup wizard in my application if i use keydown it shows incorrect values while typing on input fields

```
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <textarea></textarea><label class="input_label w-100 text-right" style="font-size:11px ;"></label>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <textarea></textarea><label class="input_label w-100 text-right" style="font-size:11px ;"></label>
</div>
<hr/>

$(document).on('keydown','input[type="text"],textarea ',function(){
    tag_name = $(this).prop("tagName")
    if(tag_name == 'TEXTAREA'){
        limit = 200
        limit_warning = 179
        $(this).attr('maxlength',200,)
    }
    else{
        limit = 20  
        limit_warning = 15
        $(this).attr('maxlength',20,)
    }
    this_vall = $(this).val()
    length_count = this_vall.length
    var text_field = length_count + "/" + limit;
    label_tag = $(this).siblings('label')
    is_label_exist = label_tag.length
    
    if(is_label_exist <1){
        x =  ` <label class="input_label w-100 text-right" style="font-size:11px ;">${text_field}</label>`
        $(this).parent().append(x)
        $(label_tag).text(text_field)
    }
    else{
        $(label_tag).text(text_field)
    }
```

Comment: can you provide a bit of your example HTML?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML

Comment: added it check it

Comment: brooo please have a look on my issue bro
here the link 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/74989417/14245434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use input, it can handle paste too

Also DRY and don't bleed vars into global scope

Lastly if you have something called exists, then don't use it as not exists

```js
$(document).on('input', 'input[type="text"],textarea ', function() {
  const tag_name = $(this).prop("tagName");
  const isTextArea = tag_name === 'TEXTAREA';
  const limit = isTextArea ? 200 : 20;
  const limit_warning = isTextArea ? 179 : 15;
  $(this).attr('maxlength', limit);
  let this_vall = $(this).val();
  let length_count = this_vall.length;
  let text_field = length_count + "/" + limit;
  let label_tag = $(this).siblings('label');
  let is_label_exist = label_tag.length > 0;

  if (!is_label_exist) {
    x = ` <label class="input_label w-100 text-right" style="font-size:11px ;">${text_field}</label>`
    $(this).parent().append(x)
  }
  $(label_tag).text(text_field)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
200 chars:
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin dolor nunc, suscipit in posuere quis, eleifend ut tortor. Quisque ullamcorper massa leo, vel euismod est dignissim nec. Nulla in eros ac.</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <textarea></textarea><label class="input_label w-100 text-right" style="font-size:11px ;"></label>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <textarea></textarea><label class="input_label w-100 text-right" style="font-size:11px ;"></label>
</div>
<hr/>
```

Comment: am trying to vote up apperantly it shows>>>>>> Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.